# Space Complexity of flattening 2d array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, space-complexity

say, I'm flattening a 2d array and putting the values in a new array
would the space complexity be *O(n * m)* where *n* is the size of the outer array and *m* is the size of the inner array which would be say the largest inner array. Or would the space complexity just be *O(n)*

```
let 2dArray = [[2, 1, 5], [7, 3], [8, 9, 11, 12]]
let flat = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 2dArray.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < 2dArray[i].length; j++){
     flat.push(2dArray[i][j]);
  }
}
```

output: `[2, 1, 5, 7, 3, 8, 9, 11, 12]`

Comment: Well obviously if you have to store up to `n * m` values the space complexity is *O(n * m)*. Why would it be just *O(n)* ?

Comment: @derpirscher OK, that makes sense. If I was looking for a specific value to push. instead of pushing every number. It would be O(n) where n would be the number of target values I've found right?